# Correct way to pass a prop to a component in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native and I don't fully understand the difference between passing in a prop as a string vs passing in as an object by using `{}`.

I couldn't find an answer that describes the difference or that tells which is the correct way, only that `{}` is used most of the time.

This is my parent component

```
const ImageScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <ImageDetail imageTitle="Forest" imageSource={require('../../assets/forest.jpg')} imageScore="9" />
            <ImageDetail imageTitle="Beach" imageSource={require('../../assets/beach.jpg')} imageScore={2} />
            <ImageDetail imageTitle="Mountain" imageSource={require('../../assets/mountain.jpg')} imageScore="4" />
        </View>
    );
};
```

Over in the `ImageDetail` component I'm rendering the props like this:

```
const ImageDetail = (props) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Image source={props.imageSource} />
            <Text>{props.imageTitle}</Text>
            <Text>Image Score: {props.imageScore}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};
```

The values are passed in correctly and it displays fine. But my question is, what is the a difference between passing in a prop as a string such as `imageScore="9"` and `imageScore={2}` ? If so, what is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing a prop there are different scenarios

if the prop is an integer use

```
 <ImageDetail intValue={9}  />
```

if the prop is a string use

```
<ImageDetail stringValue="Hello"  />
```